# Is there a site as good as Smashing Magazine geared towards drupal rather than wordpress?

Tags: nodes

As the title says, I'd like to find a site that is similar to the [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) site that caters more to drupal users.

I love this site. I have yet to find a Drupal centered one that keeps me checking the feed so often for quality content.

I'll try any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check [Planet Drupal](http://drupal.org/planet) often. I've set it up on Flipboard on the iPad. You can also setup an RSS reader to find you Drupal content.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have been trying to make such a website [www.techiestuffs.com](http://www.techiestuffs.com), but since I haven't found authors to write drupal based content I have scattered the site with categories I am comfortable with. If I find authors I will work with them.

Comment: There's not so much [Drupal content](http://www.techiestuffs.com/search/node/drupal) on your website, was the goal to cover Drupal stuff or build a site like Smashing using Drupal ?

Comment: My first thought was to build a theme like mashable and other news site and I did it but then when comes to content I know about Drupal than any other thing so i decided to concentrate more on Drupal ad web designing.it is launched just a week ago so there is not much content but I am working on that.